# Pandas: use array index all values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select all rows with a particular index. My DataFrame look like this:

```
>>> df
                            Code
Patient Date                        
1       2003-01-12 00:00:00  a
        2003-02-13 00:00:00  b
        2003-02-14 00:00:00  ba
2       2001-1-17 22:00:00  z
        2002-1-21 00:00:00  d
        2003-1-21 00:00:00  a
        2005-12-1 00:00:00  ba
```

Selecting one of the first (Patient) index works:

```
>>> df.loc[1]
                            Code
Patient Date                        
1       2003-01-12 00:00:00  a
        2003-02-13 00:00:00  b
        2003-02-14 00:00:00  ba
```

But selecting multiple of the first (Patient) index does not:

```
>>> df.loc[[1, 2]]
                            Code
Patient Date                        
1       2003-01-12 00:00:00  a
2       2001-1-17 22:00:00  z
```

However, I would like to get the entire dataframe (as the result would be if `[1,1,1,2]` i.e, the original dataframe).

When using a single index it works fine. For example:

```
>>> df.reset_index().set_index("Patient").loc[[1, 2]]
                   Date     Code
Patient                          
1       2003-01-12 00:00:00  a
        2003-02-13 00:00:00  b
        2003-02-14 00:00:00  ba
2       2001-1-17 22:00:00  z
        2002-1-21 00:00:00  d
        2003-1-21 00:00:00  a
        2005-12-1 00:00:00  ba
```

TL;DR Why do I have to repeat the index when using multiple indexes but not when I use a single index?

EDIT: Apparently it can be done similar to:

```
>>> df.loc[df.index.get_level_values("Patient").isin([1, 2])]
```

But this seems quite dirty to me. Is this *the* way - or is any other, better, way possible?

Comment: df.loc[1][1:2] should select two lines

Comment: what version pandas? can u show df.info()?

Comment: @Jeff I also get this with 0.13 and 0.14. Only in 0.14 you can do `df.loc[([1,2],),:]` to get what you want.

Comment: by the way, is it possible to achieve the same without `KeyError`s. I.e. if i do `df.loc[([1,3],),:]` when 3 is missing - only the result for 1 is returned

Comment: this was a non-trivial bug, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Pandas verison 0.14 the recommended way, according to the above comment, is:

```
df.loc[([1,2],),:]
```